# How do I access the Phone field (Event standard field) on a formula on Activity?

Tags: formula, formula-field, activity

I'm trying to create a custom formula field on Activity that looks something like this:

SUBSTITUTE(Phone, '-', '')

However, the syntax checker says the Phone field simply doesn't exist, even though it is part of the Event standard fields.

Is this a limitation? How do I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the Phone field in a formula. While I couldn't seem to find a specific document that addresses this, there is an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000Tr5xQAC) you can vote on. We have never been able to use the Phone field on Activity, necessitating additional logic, like triggers, to make this work.